# xcode 4.5 runs ios 4.0 simulator (NOT)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I just upgrade to iOS 6 xcode 4.5
But I found that even in Xcode-reference-download there are only ios 5,6
I prefer my app to work also for the users using iOS 4.X

Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: iOS 4 is no longer supported in Xcode 4.5

Comment: @phix23 Incorrect...iOS < 4.3 is no longer supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Lion, you can still download the 4.3 simulator (at least I did with the Gold Master version, supposedly it still works with the final release).

On Mountain Lion, the 4.3 simulator is buggy (as seen in the first betas) and has thus been removed by Apple.

If you really need to, you can run Lion on top of Moutain Lion with Parallels Desktop or something similar, that's what I do.

Comment: can you confirm, that this really works on Lion using the final Xcode 4.5 ?

Comment: Parallels Desktop? do you mean VMWare/VirtualBox

Comment: @phix23 I can't confirm right now. Will be doing the update from GM to final this week-end.

Comment: @user262325 It should work with VMWare/VirtualBox too, for my part I use Parallels to virtualize Windows/MacOS and VMWare to virtualize Linux.

Comment: I really confused, is it possible to create a target support ios4,5,6 simultaneously?

Comment: Starting with XCode 4.5, you can no longer target something that's below 4.3. So the broadest you can do, is: **set Base SDK to iOS 6** (so that you compile against the newest frameworks), and **set the Deployment target to 4.3** (the oldest version your code will run on). Be sure to perform adequate runtime checks to see if the APIs you use are supported.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that it works on Lion with Xcode 4.5
(Simulator 4.3)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**XCode 4.5.x only supports armv7 architecture :**

Changes in Xcode 4.5.x for ios 6

1. Xcode 4.5.x (and later) does not support generating armv6 binaries.
2. Now includes iPhone 5/armv7s support.
3. **The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5.x or later is iOS 4.3**.
4. The minimum support for iPhone is iPhone 3GS or later as earlier versions use armv6.

Hope this helps....

Comment: how does this help? he wants to run the 4.3 simulator.