# Does xcode4.5 support ios4.3 simulator or prior?

Tags: xcode

I have upgrade to xcode4.5 from 4.4, but i can't find ios simulator 4 or prior within it. I open Xcode menu, preference, downloads, i can see simulator5 and 5.1 only. I am not sure whether xcode4.5 support ios simulator 4 and debugging with ios4.3 and prior.i know almost iphone and ipad people upgrade their ios to 5 already. but we have some project runs in ios 4.3.does someone know how to install simulator 4 in xcode 4.5?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11651773/716216

Comment: I have upgraded to xcode4.5.1. Now xcode support iOS 4.3 well, without bug like Xcode4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has been removed from xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion: 
[xcode 4.5 runs ios 4.0 simulator (NOT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511191/xcode-4-5-runs-ios-4-0-simulator-not)

According to Apple you can still set the deployment target for 4.3 though: 
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3461

> The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5 or later is iOS 4.3.